# Twoway data binding form exception

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Hi I am getting the following error on my form

```
EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'Advertising'. Current value: 'Contractors'.
```

here is my html form

```
<form [formGroup]='billTypesForm' (ngSubmit)="submitForm(billTypesForm.value)">

    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>percentage</th>
        <th>out of scope</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      <tr *ngFor='let billType of billTypes; let i = index'>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]="billType.id" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['id']" />

        <td class="name">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="billType.name" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['name']" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="percentage">
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="percentage"  [(ngModel)]="billType.percentage" readonly placeholder="Tax" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['percentage']" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="outOfScope">
          <input type="checkbox" name="outOfScope"  [(ngModel)]="billType.outOfScope"  [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['outOfScope']" />
        </td>

        <input type="hidden" name="active" [(ngModel)]="billType.active"  [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['active']" />

        <td class="edit" onclick="deleteBillTypeRow($(this));">
          <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </td>

      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

The problem seems to be around [(ngModel)]="billType.name" in the input text boxes

here is my component

```
    import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms'
import {BillTypesDataService} from './bill-types-data.service'
import {BillTypes} from "./bill-types";

@Component({
  selector: 'brightbook-bill-types',
  templateUrl: './bill-types.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bill-types.component.css'],
})
export class BillTypesComponent implements OnInit {

  billTypesForm : FormGroup;
  public billTypes: BillTypes;

  constructor(private billTypesService: BillTypesDataService, fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.billTypesForm = fb.group({
        'id':[''],
        'name':[''],
        'percentage':[''],
        'outOfScope':[''],
        'active':['']

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.billTypesService.getBillTypes()
    .subscribe(
      (res:BillTypes) => this.billTypes = res,
      error =>  console.log( <any>error)
    );
  }
```

and here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import {BillTypes} from './bill-types'

import {Observable} from "rxjs";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class BillTypesDataService {

  private billTypesUrl = '/settings/bill-types/json';

  billTypes: BillTypes[] = [];

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getBillTypes() {
    return this.http.get(this.billTypesUrl)
      .map(res => <BillTypes[]> res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError (error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw('Internal server error');
  }

}
```

this is the json I am getting back from the end point call

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Advertising",
    "percentage": 0.5,
    "outOfScope": false,
    "active": true,
    "created": null
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Car & Truck Expenses",
    "percentage": 1,
    "outOfScope": false,
    "active": true,
    "created": null
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Contractors",
    "percentage": 0,
    "outOfScope": false,
    "active": true,
    "created": null
  }
]
```

I have a model class that looks like this

```
export class BillTypes {
  constructor(
  public id:string,
  public name:string,
  public percentage:number,
  public outOfScope:boolean,
  public active:boolean,
  public dateCreate:string,
  ){}
}
```

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: For what are you using the `[(ngModel)]`? Doesn't `[formControl]`/`formControlName` works fine for you?

Comment: @developer033 I am trying to bind the data that I get from http get request to my form input. `[formControl]/formControlName` doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: Does this error happens after you modify the `name` *field*?

Comment: @developer033 this error happens when i load the page which has the form on it.

Comment: Well.. look at your `code`... you're attributing each row to the same `control`. Not sure, but I guess you must use `FormArray` in this case. Btw, @A.Tim's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that your form goes crazy. You created 1 instance for each field `this.billTypesForm = fb.group({})` and then you use *same* fields for each row. Try to create new formGroup for each row...

Update:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'brightbook-bill-types',
    templateUrl: './bill-types.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bill-types.component.css'],
})
export class BillTypesComponent implements OnInit {

    public billTypes: BillTypes;

    constructor(private billTypesService: BillTypesDataService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.billTypesService.getBillTypes()
        .subscribe(
             (res:BillTypes) => this.billTypes = res,
             error =>  console.log( <any>error)
        );
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'brightbook-bill-item',
    templateUrl: './bill-item.component.html'
})
export class BrItem{

    billTypesForm : FormGroup;

    @Input()billType: BillType;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder){
        this.billTypesForm = fb.group({
            'id':[''],
            'name':[''],
            'percentage':[''],
            'outOfScope':[''],
            'active':['']
        });
    }
}
```

bill-item.component.html

```
<tr>
<form [formGroup]='billTypesForm' (ngSubmit)="submitForm(billTypesForm.value)">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" [(ngModel)]="billType.id" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['id']" />

        <td class="name">
           <div class="input-field">
             <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="billType.name" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['name']" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="percentage">
           <div class="input-field">
             <input type="text" name="percentage"  [(ngModel)]="billType.percentage" readonly placeholder="Tax" [formControl]="billTypesForm.controls['percentage']" />
          </div>
        </td>
    ...
</form>
</tr>
```

bill-types.component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>percentage</th>
    <th>out of scope</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <bill-item [billType]="billType" *ngFor='let billType of billTypes;'></bill-item>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand quite what you mean. Could you maybe give me an example? thanks.

Comment: Will try to explain... Generated HTML template after applying `ngFor` is: `<form [form]="form"> <input [formControl]="id"><input [formControl]="name"><input [formControl]="percentage>...<input [formControl]="id"><input [formControl]="name"><input [formControl]="percentage>...</form>"`. So you have 5 `FormControls` and 15 inputs. Same `FormControl` is used in 3 different inputs. You must have NEW `FormGroup` for each `BillType` instance. `<form [form]="form2"><input [formControl]="name1"></form>...<form [form]="form2"><input [formControl]="name2"></form>`

Comment: I have updated component to the following 
`  constructor(private billTypesService: BillTypesDataService, fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.billTypesForm = new FormGroup({
        id:new FormControl(''),
        name: new FormControl(''),
        percentage: new FormControl(''),
        outOfScope:new FormControl(''),
        active: new FormControl('')
    }); }` and in my html I have the following `  <input type="text" *ngFor='let billType of billTypes'name="name" placeholder="Name" [ngModel]="billType.name" formControlName="name"/>` But this only outputs the last element in the list

Comment: I am not sure if I am heading the right direction here.

Comment: @A.Tim, shouldn't it be `<bill-item [billType]="billType"` instead of `<bill-item bill-type="billType"`?

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Forgot that it is angular2, not angularJS

Comment: Thanks guys and @A.Tim thanks for your help, my issue is now resolved.